# Move the SQL Server MDF files to new drive location temporarily and move it back to original drive

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, azure

**Current resource and requirement**

I have an Azure VM running Windows Server 2012 R2. I want to upgrade its size from current 4 cores, 7 GB Memory to 8 cores, 56 GB Memory. Before upgrading, I need to move the database files from the Temporary Storage D drive to another disk drive (say E).

**Problem**

I accidentally setup my database files in the temporary storage drive without realizing that upgrading the size of the VM would result in loss of data within that drive. The database files are used by an application running in the VM.

**Plan**

My current approach is to shut down the application and SQL services (SQL Server 2008 R2) and set it to disabled. Then, I need to move the `.MDF` files from temporary storage D into another drive E. Then, I plan to change the temporary storage D into temporary storage E, and set the drive E as Local Disk D. The next step would be to upgrade the VM size. The application is from some other vendor, and they have confirmed that if the application and the SQL services are disabled, moving the SQL MDF files should not affect operation of the application.

**Question**

So, I would like to know the best method to move database files from temporary storage D to another drive E.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure I didn't follow all of your move temp storage to e to d to.... but it doesn't matter.  There are a few ways to accomplish what you want.  One of the easiest.

- Detach database
- Move Files to New Location
- Attach database

That's it when you re-attach the directory, drive, whatever can be completely different than what you started with so whatever you do with temp e/d/.... it doesn't matter to sql-server.

Note if you try moving the database without first Detaching it then you are in for a big headache!